# vba insert range into a specific column

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim CopyRng As Range
LastR = LastRow(Sheets("Sheet3"))
startrow = 1
startrow = startrow + 1
Set CopyRng = Sheets("Sheet3").Range(Sheets("Sheet3").Rows(1), Sheets("Sheet3").Rows(LastR))

    'insert copied data in Sheet3 onto inserted rows
    CopyRng.Copy ActiveSheet.Cells(startrow, 2)
```

Trying to insert CopyRng into column B, when running the code CopyRng ends up in column A

Answer (score 1):

your code is not complete, so I guess you could be after something like follows:

```
With Sheets("Sheet3") '<--| reference "Sheet3"
    ... your other code

    Set CopyRng = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range(.Rows(1), .Rows(LastR))) '<--| set 'CopyRng' to a "finite" range (not an entire row) 

        'insert copied data in Sheet3 onto inserted rows
        CopyRng.Copy ActiveSheet.cells(startrow, 2) '<--| paste the "finite" range in Activesheet

        ... your other code 
End With
```

Comment: @coffeepls, did you get through it?